# How to create new column in my data frame by condition's

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I'm trying to creating a new column in my data frame by the follow condition's :

1. If the value in `Date_of_basket_entry`is `NAN` then respond 0.
2. If the value in `Date_of_basket_entry`is greater(DATE STILL IN THE
   FUTURE) then in `month_year` then respond 1.
3. If the value in `Date_of_basket_entry`is lower (DATE STILL IN THE
   PAST) then in `month_year` then respond 0.

   ```
   month_year  Date_of_basket_entry
   0   03/2017 01.04.2005
   1   02/2019 01.01.1995
   2   07/2017 None
   4   02/2017 None
   5   04/2017 01.01.2020
   ```

it should be something like this:

```
  month_year    Date_of_basket_entry  Date_of_basket_boolean
    0   03/2017     01.04.2005                0
    1   02/2019     01.01.1995                0 
    2   07/2017     None                      0
    4   02/2017     None                      0
    5   04/2017     01.01.2020                1
```

Comment: Take a look at numpy.where - https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Danielhab I like np.where for this situation.

```py
import numpy as np

# if dtype is wrong the condition won't work correctly
df = df.astype(np.datetime64)
df.loc[:, 'Date_of_basket_boolean'] = np.where((df.Date_of_basket_entry.isna()) | (df.Date_of_basket_entry < df.month_year), 0, 1)
```

I think this should work, just check your logic.

Comment: Given the format of the columns, I don't think `(Date_of_basket_entry < month_year)` would work.

Comment: @Jorge the logic is good. when I'm trying to run this it tell `NameError: name 'Date_of_basket_entry' is not defined` , I  don't understand why. please help

Comment: @Danielhab check it again, I did some edits which should work for you

Comment: @Danielhab Karol's edits are perfect. Apologies did not noticed the data format in my original response. I check the edited one and works for the example. Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be difficult to compare month/year to month.day.year. I would start by converting columns to have the same structure. Then you can use numpy's np.where function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'month_year':['03/2017','02/2019', '07/2017', '02/2017', '04/2017'],
               'Date_of_basket_entry':['1.04.2005','01.01.1995', None, None, '01.01.2020']})

df['new1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month_year'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df['new2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_of_basket_entry'], infer_datetime_format=True)
print(df)

  month_year Date_of_basket_entry       new1       new2
0    03/2017            1.04.2005 2017-03-01 2005-01-04
1    02/2019           01.01.1995 2019-02-01 1995-01-01
2    07/2017                 None 2017-07-01        NaT
3    02/2017                 None 2017-02-01        NaT
4    04/2017           01.01.2020 2017-04-01 2020-01-01

df['Date_of_basket_boolean'] = np.where(df['new2']>df['new1'],1,0)
print(df)

  month_year Date_of_basket_entry       new1       new2  Date_of_basket_boolean
0    03/2017            1.04.2005 2017-03-01 2005-01-04                       0
1    02/2019           01.01.1995 2019-02-01 1995-01-01                       0
2    07/2017                 None 2017-07-01        NaT                       0
3    02/2017                 None 2017-02-01        NaT                       0
4    04/2017           01.01.2020 2017-04-01 2020-01-01                       1
```